# Depend on the pick list value, Hide table column in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I have a Pick list called myPicklist, when someone click on the pick list values I want Hide and show Column in below table. So far I would be able to hide, but when I select another value from pick list it does nothing.  Nothing will change, it will stay same.  Does anybody know how to change that? Thanks

**VF**

```
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="thePageBlockSection">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Product_Format__c}" onchange="myPicklistChanged();" id="myPicklist"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <table id="table_section4" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>QUANTITY</th>
                        <th>UNIT SIZE FILL VOLUME</th> 
                        <th Id="hidecolumn ">LIQUID<br/>PACKAGING</th>
                        <th>POWDER AGT<br/>PACKAGING</th>
                        <th>TOTAL<br/>VOLUME:</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity1_1__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_1__c}"/></td> 
                        <td Id="hidecolumn1"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_1__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_1__c}" /></td>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Total_Volume1_1__c}"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity1_2__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_2__c}"/></td> 
                        <td id="hidecolumn2"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_2__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_2__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Total_Volume1_2__c}"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>           
        </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>

<script>
function myPicklistChanged(){
    var myPicklistElement = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockSection.myPicklist}');
    var myPicklistValue = myPicklistElement.options[myPicklistElement.selectedIndex].value;

    if (myPicklistValue == 'Biochemical Repack'){
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your Javascript is never showing anything - the first time the picklist is changed, it might hide the elements, but after that you have no code that would revert any elements from hidden. Also, where are the "wade1 - wade3" elements? I would also recommend using jQuery for this, if you're familiar

Comment: I Fixed the elements. My problem is how do you refresh when pick list value change.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - where in your Javascript do you ever make a hidden element visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, add an else statement like this:

function myPicklistChanged(){
    var myPicklistElement = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockSection.myPicklist}');
    var myPicklistValue = myPicklistElement.options[myPicklistElement.selectedIndex].value;

    if (myPicklistValue == 'Biochemical Repack'){
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

**else{   
document.getElementById("hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "visible";}
    }**

Comment: else{ document.getElementById("hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "visible"; document.getElementById("hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "visible"; document.getElementById("hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "visible";}